# Strange behaviour of Symmetric NMF with L1-norm distance

Tags: spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition, nonnegative-matrices

I am trying to validate a symmetric NMF model based on the L1-norm distance, that is

$$min_{U\geq0} \|X - UU^T\|_1$$

However, after implementing it, I got very strange results.
The model works very well on synthetic data and fails with real world data ( mainly, face images data).
I tried both dense similarity matrices and sparse ones, but nothing help!
Does anyone have experienced similar issues?